# MySQL TIME function unexpected results

Tags: mysql

I need to be able to pull data only between specified times, regardless of how large the date range is. Eg, only retrieve records between 10:00 to 11:00 for every day in the date range.

I thought I had it nailed down until a user specified a time that crosses midnight and it returns no data.

This is my query that returns no data (using the DATE and TIME functions):

```
SELECT
 an.descr_agente as Agent,
 COUNT(if(ql.queue IN (9100, 9102, 9104),1, null)) as UK,
 COUNT(if(ql.queue IN (9200, 9202, 9204),1, null)) as AU,
 COUNT(if(ql.queue IN (9400, 9402, 9404),1, null)) as CA
FROM queue_log ql
LEFT JOIN agenti_noti an
 ON ql.agent = an.nome_agente
WHERE ql.partition = 'P001'
AND DATE(from_unixtime(ql.time_id)) BETWEEN '2017-10-03' AND '2017-10-04'
AND TIME(from_unixtime(ql.time_id)) BETWEEN '16:00' AND '01:01'
AND ql.verb IN ('COMPLETECALLER','COMPLETEAGENT','TRANSFER')
AND an.descr_agente IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY an.descr_agente
```

If I change it to below, it works, but of course it will have incorrect data once the user increases the date range more than 1 day.

```
SELECT
 an.descr_agente as Agent,
 COUNT(if(ql.queue IN (9100, 9102, 9104),1, null)) as UK,
 COUNT(if(ql.queue IN (9200, 9202, 9204),1, null)) as AU,
 COUNT(if(ql.queue IN (9400, 9402, 9404),1, null)) as CA
FROM queue_log ql
LEFT JOIN agenti_noti an
 ON ql.agent = an.nome_agente
WHERE ql.partition = 'P001'
AND from_unixtime(ql.time_id) BETWEEN '2017-10-03 16:00' AND '2017-10-04 01:01'
AND ql.verb IN ('COMPLETECALLER','COMPLETEAGENT','TRANSFER')
AND an.descr_agente IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY an.descr_agente
```

I assume the TIME function won't overlap into the next day automatically. What should I do for this to work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AND (TIME(from_unixtime(ql.time_id)) BETWEEN '16:00' AND '23:59'   
OR TIME(from_unixtime(ql.time_id)) BETWEEN '00:00' AND 01:01')
```

This might require some UI changes or additional functionality to detect the crossover and create the split,

Comment: Ah I was hoping I wouldn't have to split it like that. The UI is HTML/PHP & Javascript, guess I'll just have add more checks in place to add that in.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert, but couldn’t you use date_format ? Something like: DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(ql.time_id), ‘%Y-%m-%d %H:%i’) BETWEEN ‘2017-10-03 16:00’ AND ‘2017-10-04 01:01’